# Create a ggplot2 geom for a line and confidence interval

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to design a geom to plot a line with a confidence interval around it. The data frame that this will be based on contains the following:

1. The x values
2. The y values of the main line at each x value
3. The standard error of y=f(x) for each x

For example,

```
xvals <- seq(0,2*pi,length=100)
df <- data.frame(x=xvals, y=sin(xvals), se=.25)
head(df)
     x           y   se
1 0.00 0.000000000 0.25
2 0.01 0.009999833 0.25
3 0.02 0.019998667 0.25
4 0.03 0.029995500 0.25
5 0.04 0.039989334 0.25
6 0.05 0.049979169 0.25
```

I followed the guidelines laid out [here](http://rpubs.com/hadley/97970) to write the following geom function:

```
geom_myci <- function(yvar, sevar) {
  list(geom_ribbon(mapping=aes_q(ymin=substitute(yvar-1.96*sevar),
                                 ymax=substitute(yvar+1.96*sevar)),
                   colour="lightgrey", fill="lightgrey"),
       geom_line(mapping=aes_q(y=substitute(yvar)), lwd=2),
       theme_bw())
}
```

This can be then executed using:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_myci(y,se)
```

This works great, the only thing I don't like is I make the user enter the y variable twice. Is there any way, within the `geom` function, to know the variable that is already mapped to "y"?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via `aes_string` with `substitute` of the *se*-Variable as follows - Have a look at http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html to see how `substitute` and lazy evaluation works

```
geom_myci <- function(se_var = se) {
  se_var <- as.character(substitute(se_var))
  list(geom_ribbon(aes_string(ymin = sprintf("y - 1.96 * %s", se_var),
                              ymax = sprintf("y + 1.96 * %s", se_var)),
                   colour="lightgrey", fill="lightgrey"),
       geom_line(lwd=2),
       theme_bw())
}
```

`as.character(substitute(se_var))` makes `se_var` a sting. In this example `"se"`. Now you can use this to build the aes_string via `sprintf("y - 1.96 * %s", se_var)` which results in
`"y - 1.96 * se"` - the string we need.

Plotting it results (as asked for) in

```
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_myci()
```

[image]

Comment: This works for the example I gave, only because I called the `y` variable `"y"` in the data frame. However, what if the `y` variable in the data frame was called something else, like `"estimate"` or `"value"`? I would like a solution where the function I create somehow knows which variable is already mapped to the `y` aesthetic, or alternatively (equivalently?) to extract that variable somehow.